# Check if stored date is over 10days

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've recorded a `stored date` in MySQL database. How can I compare if the `stored date` is over 10days to date?

The stored date format is `YYYY-m-d` (2015.01.01)

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($result as $val){
  $dbDate = $val["storedDate"];
}
```

Comment: something like `strtotime($dbDate) < strtotime("-10 days")`

Comment: @adeneo thanks. But doesn't `strtotime("-10 days")` calculate 10days from today rather than 10 days from the stored date?

Comment: Then you just do `+10 days` instead, I didn't really get the *"if the stored date is over 10days to date"*, and what way you wanted to compare that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($result as $val){
    if((time() - strtotime($val["storedDate"])) > (60 * 60 * 24 * 10)){
        //do something
    }
}
```